# How can this be done with the relationship, and is it worth it? (Get all departments for clinic)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables:

**clinics**

[image: clinics]

**departments**

[image: Departmens]

**clinics_in_departments**

[image: clinics_in_departments]

Using Query Builder:

```
$department = ClinicsInDepartment::whereIn('clinic_id',[1,2,3])
            ->join('departments', 'clinics_in_departments.department_id', '=', 'departments.id')
            ->get();
```

### How can this be done with the relationship, and is it worth it?

Comment: this can be done by many to many relationship in eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of Laravel at the Many to Many section https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many it's already explained in there. If you're planning to keep using Laravel I would recommend using the best practises of Eloquent. It's easier to understand and read for other developers. It's always worth to make your product the best you can. It also gives possibilities to quickly extend and maintain your application.

**All you need to do is to define a relationship in your model clinics**

```
// second, third and fourth parameter could also be optional
function departments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clinics', 'clinics_in_departments', 'department_id', 'clinic_id');
}
```

**To retrieve the data you can use**

```
$clinics = Clinics::with('departments')->get();
// this would hold a list of departments for each clinic
```

**To get exactly the same data extend the query to this**

```
$clinics = Clinics::with('departments')->whereIn('clinic_id',[1,2,3])->get();
```

Because it's a Many to Many relationship you could also define a relationship for the model **Departments** and do exactly the same as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a belongs to many relation inside Clinics model like below code

```
 function departments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Clinics', 'clinics_in_departments');
 }
```